# Django 3 ModelChoiceField stays empty

Tags: django

I have this form with two fields. The second field should be populated with the names of existing projects but when rendered is stays empty and no dropdown appears.

```
class UploadRawForm(forms.ModelForm):
    orig_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RawFile
        fields = ['orig_file', 'project']
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}File upload{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
    <h1> {{ name }} </h1>
    <form method="POST" id="upload-form" class="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </form>

    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p> {{ error }} </p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='accounts/login')
def upload_raw_view(request):
    '''Upload RAW files. Working for single file uploads'''
    form = UploadRawForm()
    name = 'Upload RAW files.'
    context = {'form': form, 'name': name}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadRawForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context['form'] = form
        if not form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'proteomics/upload.html', context=context)
        if form.is_valid():
            files = request.FILES.getlist('orig_file')
            for f in files:
                rawfile = RawFile(orig_file=f)
                rawfile.save()
            return render(request, 'proteomics/upload.html', context)
    return render(request, 'proteomics/upload.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class RawFile(models.Model):
    # use the custom storage class fo the FileField
    orig_file = models.FileField(upload_to = media_file_name, 
                                 storage = public_storage, 
                                 max_length = 1000)
    md5sum = models.CharField(max_length = 36, 
                              default = timezone.now, 
                              unique = True)
    created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Saving new raw file.', self.md5sum)
        if not self.pk:  # file is new
            md5 = hashlib.md5()
            for chunk in self.orig_file.chunks():
                md5.update(chunk)
            self.md5sum = md5.hexdigest()
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        print('Saving new raw file.', self.md5sum)

        try:
            super(RawFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        except IntegrityError as e:
            pass

    def __str__(self):
        return basename(self.orig_file.name)

    @property
    def abs_path(self): 
        return f'{PUBLIC_MEDIA_ROOT}/{self.orig_file}'

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return basename(self.abs_path)

    @property
    def path(self):
        return dirname(self.abs_path)

    @property
    def rawtools_status(self):
        path = dirname(self.abs_path)
        if isfile('QcDataTable.csv'):
            return 'Done'
        elif isfile(join(path, 'rawtools.txt')):
            return 'Running'
        return 'New file'

    @property    
    def href(self):
        return os.path.dirname('/'+self.orig_file.name)

    def link(self):
        print(self.href)
        return mark_safe(r'<a href="{}">Output</a>'.format(self.href))

    link.short_description = 'Browse'
```

[image]

## Versions

```
django                    3.0.5            py36h9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
django-admin-index        1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
django-extensions         2.2.9              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
django-ordered-model      3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
django-plotly-dash        1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

## The available projects appear in the HTML code though:

```
    <form method="POST" id="upload-form" class="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="BCns828qAZlisCkj31ITefv5fn3YugsUIZRGsR5wfKnRyL2XTAvDsdWOKX2TSaKQ">
        <p><label for="id_orig_file">Orig file:</label> <input type="file" name="orig_file" multiple required id="id_orig_file"></p>
<p><label for="id_project">Project:</label> <select name="project" required id="id_project">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">COVID</option>

  <option value="2">LSARP</option>

</select></p>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: just for confirmation, does your `Project` model contain at least one data?

Comment: Yes................needed to add more characters.

Comment: That code looks ok. Perhaps the problem is in the model or view

Comment: I added that code as well.

Comment: I get a dropdown with all available projects in the admin pannel.

Comment: have you tried the modelform without overrriding the `project` field?

Comment: Not sure what that means.

Comment: I think bb4l means remove the `project = forms.ModelChoiceField(...)` from the form. You are using the `.all()` queryset, so it doesn't look like that line is doing anything. Perhaps the problem is with your `Project` model.

Comment: If the HTML is correctly rendered then check your `.css` files to see where the problem is. Why is the widget hidden?

Comment: Yup, seems to be a CSS problem

Comment: It came from materialize.css. I found a script that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Why using a ModelForm if you are redefining all the generated fields?

Here's what I would do:

```
# forms.py
class UploadRawForm(forms.ModelForm):
    orig_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta:
        model = RawFile
        fields = ['orig_file', 'project']
```

```
# views.py
@login_required(login_url='accounts/login')
def upload_raw_view(request):
    '''Upload RAW files. Working for single file uploads'''
    form = UploadRawForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    name = 'Upload RAW files.'
    context = {'form': form, 'name': name}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            files = request.FILES.getlist('orig_file')
            for f in files:
                rawfile = RawFile(orig_file=f)
                rawfile.save()
    return render(request, 'proteomics/upload.html', context)
```

Your model and template seem ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your form:

```
class UploadRawForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = RawFile
        fields = ['orig_file', 'project']
        widgets = {
            'orig_file': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

Regarding the `orig_file` field: you're only changing its widget, so you only need to add an entry to the `Meta.widgets` dict.

Regarding the `project` field: No need to completely override what was already given to you. Just modify the queryset during form initialization.  In your case, you may not even need to modify the queryset since the default is already `Project.objects.all()`. So your form can simply be:

```
class UploadRawForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RawFile
        fields = ['orig_file', 'project']
        widgets = {
            'orig_file': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The template contained materialize.css which caused the dropdown not to show up. I added

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select(); 
    });
  </script>
```

right behind the import of the materialize file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the form with previous or initial data, then when initiating the form in the `views.py` file, you should do something like this:

```
form = JournalForm(initial={'tank': 123})
```

Or, set the value in the `forms.py` file, like this:

```
tank = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=123)
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget attribute should work. Like so:

```
project = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset= Project.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': True}), empty_label='')
```